# Clicking on my web in google results redirects me back to google

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect

Im helping a friend out on a website which is created using an online platform powered by plesk and theres an issue when trying to access this web through google.

Writing the domain directly in the browser works fine but when accessing it through a google search it redirects the user back to google.

What could be the issue?

this is my **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #HTTP-HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://srad.wtf/es_ES/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

*Ive removed the majority of the comments from the file to keep it clean*

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in your Apache `.htaccess` file that would cause this redirect. However, the redirect response when navigating from Google SERPs (which incidentally, only appears to be when navigating to the homepage, not subpages) appears to be coming from an Nginx server (possibly a front-end proxy), not Apache.

Comment: @MrWhite does that mean its something that I cant solve myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, there doesn't appear to be anything in your `.htaccess` file that would cause this redirect.

> the redirect response ... appears to be coming from an Nginx server (possibly a front-end proxy), not Apache.
>
> @MrWhite does that mean its something that I cant solve myself?

The Nginx server, from which the response is ultimately being served from/through (a front-end/caching proxy I suspect) is part of your server config - so you would expect to have some control over this - although "using an online platform" then maybe not?

However, the redirect(s) you are seeing may be coming from your application server/PHP (not Nginx or Apache). The problem isn't just with "Google Chrome" (as you have tagged) or even with Google SERPs. Any inbound link to the homepage is being 302 redirected back to itself (the HTTP Referer).

Not wanting to sound alarming, but this sort of redirect is quite typical of a site being hacked - as it is potentially damaging for SEO. Although since this only affects the homepage and is a 302 (temporary) redirect and you appear to have other *language* specific redirects in the application logic then this may just be a missconfiguration - although redirecting back to the "HTTP Referer" is quite a deliberate action!

For example, the following link to your homepage currently 302 redirects back to "this page"!

- https://srad.wtf/

### Workaround

Your site appears to be in two languages, as denoted by the first path segment, `/en/` or `/es_ES/` (default). The *application logic* appears to *unconditionally* redirect(302) to `/es_ES/` if omitted (it is not deduced from the user's browser preferences or remembered for returning visitors).

You may be able to redirect to `/es_ES/` early in `.htaccess` *before* the application kicks in. (By the same logic that requesting the HTTP homepage also works OK, since it is redirected to HTTPS early in `.htaccess`.)

Try the following, after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/es_ES/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is a "workaround", it doesn't fix the underlying problem.

---

*Additionally...*

> ```
> #HTTP-HTTPS
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://srad.wtf/es_ES/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
> ```

This HTTP to HTTPS redirect is not strictly correct, as it unconditionally prefixes the request with `/es_ES/` even when a valid language code might already be present. eg. Request `http://example.com/es_ES/about` (HTTP) and you are redirected to `https://example.com/es_ES/es_ES/about` (404). etc.

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect should simply redirect to the same URL-path (resolve any other language/path issues elsewhere<sup>***1**</sup>). For example, this should be written:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `QSA` (Query String Append) flag is not required since the query string (if any) is passed through by default, unless you create a new query string on the *substitution* string (the `QSA` flag would then be required to *append* the query string from the original request).

(<sup>***1**</sup> To some extent, the preceding "workaround" resolves the missing language code.)

Strictly speaking, the *language* should be defaulted *conditionally* based on the value of the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header - but this is best done in PHP, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: Wow, great explanation, thanks so much for your time and effort, very well done!